# Matching one layer object color with another layer object color in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm kind of very beginner in QGIS. I have made one layer of "cells" and visualised them on map with different colors representing cell numbers like this:

[image]

[image: Example of layer]

The idea is that this layer is like database of the network which is always loaded in my QGIS project and sometimes I need to add some data from these cells on the map, which is loaded in another txt file(s).

I would like the points of this data to represent the same color which is stored in another layer(network database layer). Is there any way how to match these colors?

For example here below you can see the image of the 2 layers loaded together and I added labels to the points. For example how can make points with attribute number 280 to be orange or number 281 to be green?

[image: Example of layers]

Comment: You can't properly distinguish more than 20 colours in a map, so your whole idea is rather bad practice.

Comment: colors can and will repeat, but numbers are up to 500. Numbers do not repeat in close area, they are like geographically separated with a good distance from each other. Yes i found some looking same colors when numbers are close, i.e number 1 and number 2 is the same color, but overall it's looking good and it's not a big problem, since i can still manually set color for every number, if there is such need apart from random generated

Comment: Is "Cells" layer a polygon or a point layer?

Comment: If you want to change color of points based on attributes, try the categorized symbology.

Comment: You can apply the style of one layer to another. Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for helping me. Found the solution by copying symbology from one layer to another, then just changing symbol to dots. The only one disadvantage is when you want to change some specific cell color then would need to do it in two layers. I will just keep 2 layer styles one for database layer and one for imported data.
[image]